# Matching values from two separate JSON feeds

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm working on a project that is AJAX driven with multiple JSON feeds. I'm using one feed to create a list of categories, which filters articles that come in from the second feed.

My first feed looks like this:

```
"value": [
    {
        "Id": "1ca44b5b-06ab-63fa-8375-ff00000b3273",
        "Title": "Safety",
    }, ...
]
```

My second feed looks like this:

```
value": [
    {
        "Id": "30b94b5b-06ab-63fa-8375-ff00000b3273",
        "Title": "Test article",
        "Body": "Test content",
        "topics": [
            "1ca44b5b-06ab-63fa-8375-ff00000b3273"
        ],
    }, ...
]
```

The first feed is a list of topics, the second feed is a set of articles tagged by those topics. I'm able to match the GUIDs for filtering just fine, but the problem is that due to limitations of the second feed I'm unable to pull the title "Safety" into the article. I need this title for a variety of reasons, mainly styling and for pushing the title to the page URL.

I'm trying to find the best way to approach this in order to make it dynamic going forward. Basically, I want to find the best way to associate the GUID to the title in my second feed, based on my first feed.

Here's how I'm pulling the two feeds:

Feed 1:

```
$('.category-filters').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        method:"GET",
        url: '/api/stories/flat-taxa?$filter=TaxonomyId%20eq%20dca84b5b-06ab-63fa-8375-ff00000b3273',
        data: { format:'json'},
        context:$this
    }).success(function(data){

        var category = data.value;
        var filter = [];

        for (i = 0; i < category.length; i++) { 
            $this.append('<li><input type="checkbox" id="' + category[i].Id + '"><label for="' + category[i].Id + '">' + category[i].Title + '</label></li>');
        } 
    });
});
```

Feed 2:

```
function storyCards(){

    $.ajax({ 
        method:"GET",
        url: url,
        data: { format:'json' },
        context:$('.story-cards')
    }).success(function(data){ 
        var story = data.value;

        for (i = 0; i < story.length; i++) { 
            $('.story-cards').append('<li class="item card-item"><div class="card"><div class="content"><h2>' + story[i].Title + '</h2>' + story[i].Summary + '</div><div class="card-footer"><a class="button" href="' + story[i].UrlName + '">' + story[i].ButtonText + '</a></div></div></li>');
        }
    }); 
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense, happy to provide more details if requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a good place for a shared dictionary where you can match GUID to title.

```
//dynamically set the titles
var guid2title = {}
//titles is the array of titles/GUID in your post
for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
   guid2title[titles[i]["Id"]] = titles[i]["Title"];
}

//items is the json array of articles in your post
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    items[i].titles = []; //used later to save to the object
    for (var j = 0; j < items[i].topics.length; j++){
       var GUID = items[i].topics[j];
       var title = guid2title[GUID];

       //attach it to your item for later use
       items[i].titles.push(title);

    }

}
```

Comment: Seems like a good approach, definitely one I had in mind.. my issue is that in this scenario both the GUID and the title are hard coded. This client may add more categories going forward, so I can't rely on setting the vars this way. Maybe I'm misunderstanding though?

Comment: Showed how to do this with an edit. Just fetch all of the titles first, setting up your guid2title dict. Then you can reference that with the articles.

Comment: This worked like a dream, really efficient. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do some looping and add the topic title to the articles like:

```
  var obj1 = {
  "value": [{
    "Id": "1ca44b5b-06ab-63fa-8375-ff00000b3273",
    "Title": "Safety",
  }]
};

var obj2 = {
  "value": [{
    "Id": "30b94b5b-06ab-63fa-8375-ff00000b3273",
    "Title": "Test article",
    "Body": "Test content",
    "topics": [
      "1ca44b5b-06ab-63fa-8375-ff00000b3273"
    ],
  }]
};

$.each(obj2.value, function(i, v) {
  $.each(obj1.value, function(index, val) {
    if (v.topics[0] == val.Id) {
      obj2.value[i]['TopicName'] = val.Title;

    }
  });
});
console.log(obj2);
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/jrdn27rf/

in this case you can do the following:

function storyCards(){

```
$.ajax({ 
    method:"GET",
    url: url,
    data: { format:'json' },
    context:$('.story-cards')
}).success(function(data){ 
    var story = data.value;

    for (i = 0; i < story.length; i++) { 
        var categoryTitle = $('label[for="'+story[i].topics[0]+']"').text();
        $('.story-cards').append('<li class="item card-item"><div class="card"><div class="content"><h2>' + story[i].Title + '</h2>' + story[i].Summary + '</div><p>'+categoryTitle +'</p><div class="card-footer"><a class="button" href="' + story[i].UrlName + '">' + story[i].ButtonText + '</a></div></div></li>');
    }
});
```

}

Comment: I'm really liking this approach, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my solution. Updated my question with the AJAX I'm using, any chance you could expand on that?

Comment: see my updated answer, if you have multiple categories you do a loop and take the category titles